# Invertible Transforms in 3D Space

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading a book called "Foundations of 3D Computer Graphics" by Steven J. Gortler. In chapter 2 entitled "Linear" on page 14 he says:

> In computer graphics, when we choose 3D to 3D linear transforms to move objects around in space (as well as scale them), it will seldom make sense to use a noninvertible transform. So, unless stated, all of the matrices we will be dealing with in this book will have an inverse.

I'm trying to make sense of this, so I thought up an example. Is this like saying that a translation of an object 2 units to the right must be able to move back 2 units to the left? Is this what it means for operations (like a translation or a scale) on objects in a 3D space will have to be invertible? That it must be able to go back to a previous state?

Comment: Yes.  That's exactly what invertible means.  To be able to **undo** the transformation.

Comment: Yes, a transformation is invertible if there exists another transformation that takes you back to the original state.  If you rotate clockwise about some axis, you can rotate counterclockwise.  If you zoom in, you can zoom out.  An example of a non-invertible transformation would be the projection from your 3D model to your 2D representation on the screen.  From just the 2D image, you cannot recreate the 3D model.

Comment: Invertible means  you can undo it. A function is invertible if and only if it's bijective. An example of an invertible linear transformation is a rotation. An example of a linear transformation that is not invertible is orthogonal projection.